# How to export all of my own answers into a text document?

Tags: support, export

How can I export all of my own answers but only my own answers without any comments but together with the questions into a text document?

Comment: Use the API? Copy/Paste?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA I have asked how. Tell me how. If it is API say API, if it is Copy/Paste say Copy/Paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build your own App to do that. With [Answers on Users](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users) you can query for your ID in a given site. These are your first 100 answers on Stack Overflow:

> http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/402322/answers?pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow

I see that you have [99 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402322/ceving?tab=answers&sort=votes) and the result of the query has the following at the very end: `"has_more":false`. With this you'll [iterate through all pages](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging) when there are 100+ results. As pointed by Dave Chen bellow, you can [add a filter](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=402322&filter=!9j_cPvogJ&site=stackoverflow&run=true) to retrieve the body of the posts.

Take note of the [Throttling limits](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) and research on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) to see if something like this has already been built.

<sub>An example for WordPress/PHP: [How to Embed Stackexchange Account Metrics into Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18294444/1287812)</sub>

Comment: To extend, if you use [a filter](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=402322&filter=!9j_cPvogJ&site=stackoverflow&run=true), you can also include the body. You then don't need to make additional queries.

Comment: @DaveChen, still, the answer body is not too useful without the question body.