# How can I download my content from a site?

Tags: support, export

I'd like to be able to save a copy of questions on which I've participated (asked, answered, and ideally commented but that's less important) from a  site (beta, if it matters) in a human-readable form.  (Text, HTML, XML with a known schema... not picky here.)  I understand that I could [use the data explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149974/162102) to extract some of this, but not full copies as far as I know.
I see that there is [an API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) that might be able to help me if I knew webapps better or JSON at all.

Has somebody already written something like this?  Or is there some other way to do this?  Is my best bet to just download the data dump and trawl through it looking for my stuff?

(In case it matters, the specific case prompting the question is a site where I have a couple hundred posts -- not thousands, but not so few that just doing it by hand is obviously the right approach.)

I've seen [this similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194456/162102).

(When I wrote this question beta sites were not included in SEDE or the data dumps.  Now they are, but I still don't see a clean way to extract whole questions based on my participation.)

Comment: The data dump should include even Beta-Sites if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, [I'm talking about the data dump](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump).

Comment: Somewhat related: [Dump of my own Stack Exchange content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269804).

Answer (score 7):

Nice idea, great to study one's (or another's) participation in the Stack.

I just published this WordPress plugin at Stack Apps: it renders a page listing all posts from a selected user in a selected site (paginated at a maximum of 100 posts per page). With that you can export the HTML or print or save as PDF.

[image: app icon]
[**All Your Stack Posts**](https://stackapps.com/q/4306/10590)

Selecting a site in the plugin's meta box:

> [image: plugin meta box]

<sub>A [live example](http://plugins.brasofilo.com/testing-stack-app/) of the plugin in action.</sub>

Comment: Ooh, thanks!  I'm looking forward to giving this a spin tonight.  (Well, after pause for getting WordPress, but I hope that's straightforward. :-) )

Comment: I wish [Discourse](http://discourse.org/) was as easy and cheap to install as WP ;)

Comment: Sorry for the noob question (and I won't make a habit of this, I promise), but to use this do I need to host a Wordpress installation myself (as opposed to just having a blog on their site)?

Comment: Yes, self-hosted. WP.com doesn't allow installing plugins.

Comment: Live example link is dead.

Comment: Thanks, @kenorb, will check it later and ping you