# Is it possible to get my posts in a downloadable file?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

Is it possible to get my posts and the answers given on SO and other SE sites in the form of a downloadable text/html file? Similar to how tumblr allows its users to transfer their download their blog data. Thanks. If not, what is the fastest way of getting all my posts, and the answers associated with them, besides copying and pasting them manually in a text file?

Comment: the data dump, or data explorer (http://data.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I was wondering if there was a more direct way without downloading massive GB files (data dump) or running queries in data explorer across every site. After additional searching it is clear that this is not possible, so I will be engaging in the latter method. Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: The data explorer would let you limit things.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194475/162102

Answer (score 5):

You can run a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) against the data easily enough, and then download a CSV of the results.

```
SELECT 
    Qus.Title, Qus.Body, Ans.Body 
FROM Posts as Qus
LEFT JOIN Posts as Ans
ON Qus.ID = Ans.ParentID
WHERE Qus.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
    AND Qus.PostTypeId = 1
    AND Ans.PostTypeID = 2
```