# How to copy [make a backup] my Q&A or another user's in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, backup

I want to know how I can make a backup of my questions and answers or Q&A of somebody else in Stack Exchange network?

Comment: Why would you need such a backup? Any reason the [data dumps](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/) can't help you out there?

Comment: You know for practicing I think it could be very useful...I know some knowledgeable users that always have very good answers...I want to obey them in scripting

Comment: sorry...no help

Comment: Here you go http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/168028/all-posts-q-and-a-for-user-2515498

Comment: Whenever we don't like something we would downvote it?

Comment: @MortezaLSC - downvotes on Meta merely mean disagreement, often gentle disagreement. carry on, farewell

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194475/162102 (beta sites are now in SEDE but, as noted with the solution proposed here, using SEDE does have some limitations if you wanted to be able to easily read the resulting posts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user rene just shared, there's a very useful online query builder - https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/168028/all-posts-q-and-a-for-user-2515498?UserId=2515498  , and you can obtain your user ID number from the URL of  your user-profile page:

[image]

Comment: I slightly adapted the query so it now takes a parameter : http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/168028/all-posts-q-and-a-for-user-2515498?UserId=2515498

Comment: @Adel Thank you, At least upvote me :( (broken heart)

Comment: @MortezaLSC - K, you got it

Comment: @Adel When I download [a user's Q&A](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/168032) this is not what I want...not good appearence

Comment: @MortezaLSC - that's a fair point. Well there is the old fashioned-way. save each one. But you shuold be able to automate via autohotkey or selenium or smthing similar

Comment: @MortezaLSC you can download the whole data dump of Stack Overflow which contains all questions and answers in XML format. Then you can make out of it whatever you want.

Comment: But I think THIS NETWORK should have better facilities...Thank you all guys