# Download all my content in a compact form

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

The imaginary feature being proposed sounds like a lot of work to implement but I think it still can be useful as an inspiration.

Assume a user of an SE site has made some thoughtful contributions and feels like they really spent some effort on their posts. Assume the user in question does not believe in the immortality of SE and wants to have a local copy of all their contributions (questions/answers, possibly also comments). They could copy all of them by hand, or automate it somehow if they know programming but that is at least a little bit annoying. Can we make add a feature to download a .zip archive of all your content if you want to? Just like on GitHub where you can download your repo.

This leaves open the question of how exactly to represent a post in text form (tags, revision history, post time etc.) but that is technical details.

EDIT: I see that my question was closed as a duplicate. I do not think that it is a duplicate though I recognize that I may be mistaken. My reasons (a) the feature I request should not download all content, only my content (maybe I don't want to pay for extra gigabytes of traffic) (b) I also would like it to be really simple, just one click and you download it (I don't want to spend half an hour extracting what I need from the data dump through some SQL gymnastics, I would like it to be just one button).

Comment: See also [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194475/how-can-i-download-my-content-from-a-site)

Comment: The alleged duplicate: Yes, [not exactly](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange) compact. [stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z is 13.6 GB](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z).

Comment: Workaround: rate-limited (say, every 3 seconds or slower) [screen scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) by a script (say, in Perl, essentially two lines: `use LWP::Simple qw(get);` and `my $content = get $URL;` (the value of `$content` to be saved to disk, $URL from a list of URLs, `sleep(3)`, etc.))

Comment: Try this answer of mine: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269804/dump-of-my-own-stack-exchange-content/269951#269951

Comment: See also [Dump of my own Stack Exchange content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269804/157730)